# Macro to make all possible combinations of data in various columns in excel sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am a complete novice at macros and have been given a task which if done manually, can take a lot of time. I have a worksheet which has data as below:

```
A                      B           C
abc,def,ghi,jkl      1,2,3     a1,e3,h5,j8
```

I would like this to be in the following format.

```
abc  1  a1
abc  2  a1
abc  3  a1
abc  1  e3
abc  2  e3
abc  3  h5
```

and so on to make all possible combinations.
Any help will be great. Thanks

Comment: are you sure? I would try and get the input formatted better, certainly more , separation.

Comment: how do you mean all possible combinations, at the moment, you are into the millions.

Comment: @Sasquiha - I don't count millions from the OP's posted datasets, just 48... but if he wants to work with larger datasets, then it can easily grow

Answer (score 2):

Alternative method

```
Private Sub Combinations()
Dim arrA() As String, arrB() As String, arrC() As String
Dim lngA As Long, lngB As Long, lngC As Long

With Sheet1  '(CHANGE SHEET IF REQUIRED)
   arrA = Split(.Range("A1"), ",")
   arrB = Split(.Range("B1"), ",")
   arrC = Split(.Range("C1"), ",")

   For lngA = LBound(arrA) To UBound(arrA)
     For lngB = LBound(arrB) To UBound(arrB)
        For lngC = LBound(arrC) To UBound(arrC)

        .Range("I" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = arrA(lngA) & " " & arrB(lngB) &       " " & arrC(lngC)
        Next lngC
      Next lngB
    Next lngA
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Ah, I had interpreted the original data as being in columns instead of being comma separated.  This works.

Comment: Sorry about the formatting. I have quite a big dataset.I tried this macro and its not working

Comment: Actually its 3 columns A,B & C. And there are some cells like A1,B1 & C1 as above has comma separated data in them.

Comment: @UJ9 - did you mean my code isn't working? My code assumes data is in sheet with codename 'Sheet1', you may need to change it.

Comment: @UJ9, you should update your question to include that bit of information about how the data is formatted.

Answer (score 1):

This code will take the data from columns A, B, and C, and give the output you described in columns E, F, and G.

```
Sub combinations()

Dim c1() As Variant
Dim c2() As Variant
Dim c3() As Variant
Dim out() As Variant
Dim j, k, l, m As Long


Dim col1 As Range
Dim col2 As Range
Dim col3 As Range
Dim out1 As Range


Set col1 = Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown))
Set col2 = Range("B1", Range("B1").End(xlDown))
Set col3 = Range("C1", Range("C1").End(xlDown))

c1 = col1
c2 = col2
c3 = col3

Set out1 = Range("E2", Range("G2").Offset(UBound(c1) * UBound(c2) * UBound(c3)))
out = out1

j = 1
k = 1
l = 1
m = 1


Do While j <= UBound(c1)
    Do While k <= UBound(c2)
        Do While l <= UBound(c3)
            out(m, 1) = c1(j, 1)
            out(m, 2) = c2(k, 1)
            out(m, 3) = c3(l, 1)
            m = m + 1
            l = l + 1
        Loop
        l = 1
        k = k + 1
    Loop
    k = 1
    j = j + 1
Loop


out1.Value = out
End Sub
```

If on the other hand, your data is comma-separated in cells A1, B1, and C1, the following code will work similarly.

```
Sub combinations()

Dim c1() As String
Dim c2() As String
Dim c3() As String
Dim out() As Variant
Dim j, k, l, m As Long


Dim col1 As Range
Dim col2 As Range
Dim col3 As Range
Dim out1 As Range


Set col1 = Range("A1")
Set col2 = Range("B1")
Set col3 = Range("C1")

c1 = Split(col1.Value, ",")
c2 = Split(col2.Value, ",")
c3 = Split(col3.Value, ",")

Set out1 = Range("E1", Range("G1").Offset((UBound(c1) + 1) * (UBound(c2) + 1) * (UBound(c3) + 1)))
out = out1

j = 0
k = 0
l = 0
m = 1


Do While j <= UBound(c1)
    Do While k <= UBound(c2)
        Do While l <= UBound(c3)
            out(m, 1) = c1(j)
            out(m, 2) = c2(k)
            out(m, 3) = c3(l)
            m = m + 1
            l = l + 1
        Loop
        l = 0
        k = k + 1
    Loop
    k = 0
    j = j + 1
Loop
out1.Value = out
End Sub
```

Comment: Please ignore my formatting as its my first post. Excellll, I have tried your macro and it gives a run time error 6, overflow. Any suggestions?

Comment: Which macro did you use?  And could you tell me at what line the error occurs?